# Revoke access granted to my app Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

How do I revoke access that has been granted to my Google Drive web application so that upon the user's next use he is asked for permissions afresh?

Comment: Basically, I screwed up with my Datastore so I'd be needing the refresh tokens afresh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you clobbered all the refresh tokens in your DB, adding the query parameter approval_prompt=force to the auth request will fix that. It'll result in the refresh tokens getting reissued when the user next approves the request.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I can do that using the python client library?

Comment: Just pass approval_prompt=force when construction the flow. Any additional arguments get passed through as query parameters when making the auth request.

Answer (score 26):

For revoking your access token, you need to "GET" (!) this url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
where {token} is the value of your token, as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke

For Java API (don't know for other languages), as of 9th of Sept 2012, there is no API for this.
I managed to revoke a token with this code:

```
class myGoogleApi {
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    ...

    public revoke(String token) {
        HttpRequestFactory factory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
        GoogleUrl url = new GoogleUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token="+token);
        HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(url);
        HttpResponse response = request.execute();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: please let me know how could we get the json response from this request for revoking the access token?

Comment: @Karan, according to the documentation, there is no JSON response: the result is returned in the HTTP status code: "if the revocation is successfully processed, then the status code of the response is 200. For error conditions, a status code 400 is returned along with an error code."

Answer (score 4):

In order to revoke the access go to the below url

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Choose your apps that you need to revoke  and click on remove.

Answer (score 3):

Visit https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en for the list of applications and sites that you granted access to. Next to each of them you'll find a Revoke Access button.

The instructions to get to that page are at http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41236

Comment: Perhaps my question isn't clear enough. I want users of my application to be prompted for authorization the next time they try to access my app as I no longer have their refresh tokens.

Comment: Excellent answer - I came to this question needing to revoke access to a third party's application so had no idea of what the token was that they were granted. This link was exactly what was required.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Play Services:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html

Add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile to your scope.

Example:

```
String scope="oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, "xxxx@gmail.com", scope);
```

OR "brute force"

```
Intent res = new Intent();
res.addCategory("account:xxxx@gmail.com");
res.addCategory("scope:oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
res.putExtra("service", "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
Bundle extra= new Bundle();
extra.putString("androidPackageName","com.your.package");
res.putExtra("callerExtras",extra);
res.putExtra("androidPackageName","com.your.package");
res.putExtra("authAccount","xxxx@gmail.com");

String mPackage = "com.google.android.gms";
String mClass = "com.google.android.gms.auth.TokenActivity";
res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mClass));
startActivityForResult(res,100);
```

Now, when you revoke the access here https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens the application shows you the window for permission again in the device.