# How do I revoke FormEmailer's access to my Google account?

Tags: google-apps-script

A long time ago I played with google scripts but gave up and don't need anything to do with them now.

Recently I noticed that FormEmailer *(whatever that is)* was sending lots of emails to an old, rarely looked at email account of mine saying a script had failed, so something was still running.

Following the very clear instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568884/how-do-i-stop-an-apps-script-from-running) SO post I found I still had something called a trigger active and so deleted it. I now have no projects, no sheets, no docs and no triggers shown in http://script.google.com. Additionally my Chrome browser has no extensions for sheets, docs, slides, offline viewing or anything to do with google that I can see.

But I have now been sent a security alert from Google Play saying

> "FormEmailer now has access to your Google account. If you did not
> grant access, review your account's activity"

I don't understand what this means but it may be something I granted inadvertently.

Please can someone clearly tell me the steps I need to follow to remove this access  - if indeed it should be removed?

(I have looked at these SO posts [revoke access ... google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017445/revoke-access-granted-to-my-app-google-drive-api), [revoke access ... google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558356/revoke-drive-access-through-google-play-services://), [revoke access ... within extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784461/how-to-revoke-google-account-access-from-within-an-extension) but either don't understand them or they don't seem relevant)

Comment: Go to your gmail account upper right corner click on the tools icon.  Go to account/secure account find where you granted access to that mailer and remove it.

Comment: Gmail?   What does that have to do with it? As far as I know I don't have a gmail account.

Comment: If you have a google account then you have a gmail or gsuite account

Answer (score 0):

1. I searched for 'Google Login' and found a page where I could enter
   an email and password.
2. I logged in with my old, never used, email address and a password I
   haven't used for years
3. That brought up a screen with a 'security' link on it
4. I clicked that and got a page with a heading 'Third party access'
5. Under that it said FormEmailer had access to my account as flagged
   it as a security issue
6. There was a button 'remove access'
7. Clicked that button and it now says 'All third party access issues
   have been resolved'

So I think this must be the answer.

Comment: That's the answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was the Gmail that confused me